# MySQL replication replicate-do-db and replicate-ignore-db not working

Tags: mysql, replication

I have amended my.cnf with below values:

`binlog-ignore-db`                = `DB1`
`binlog-ignore-db`               = `DB2`
`binlog-ignore-db`                = `DB3`

`binlog-do-db`                   = `MYDB01`
`binlog-do-db`                    = `MYDB02`

This is to replicate data from one master to just one slave. I want to replicate only  MYDB01 and MYDB02 but I am getting various data not found errors for ignored databases (DB1, DB2,and DB3). As per my understanding it should not replicate tables from ignored schemas at all.

Please advise why isn't this working??